# Adicionado componentes no Xamarin Studio 4.x/5.x e Android Designer

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

Ao utilizar a ferramenta Interface Designer do Xamarin Studio 4.x/5.x na plataforma Windows 8/8.1 não consigo adicionar componentes na tela, ao tentar arrastar e soltar um componente da barra de ferramente para a interface o mesmo não é aplicado (fica na tela).

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Olá Vitor, bemvindo ao Stackoverflow! Este site é para perguntas e respostas. Pode editar a sua pergunta para ser uma "pergunta" e colocar a informacao de como solucionar em baixo no campo das respostas.

Comment: Aqui, o modo de dizer "resolvido" é marcar a resposta como correta (checkmark ao lado da resposta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução encontrada:**

Detectei dois possíveis problemas, que afetam diretamente a ferramenta:

1º - Versão do driver de vídeo desatualizada. Após atualizar o driver de vídeo alguns usuários conseguiram utilizar a ferramenta corretamente.

2º - Interferência de softwares de terceiro, principalmente anti-vírus e sistemas de compartilhamento de tela. Ao desabilitar os mesmos a ferramenta funciona corretamente.

Espero que isto possa ajudar a alguém que esteja enfrentando os mesmo problemas.